# How to create object with fake data in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Suppose if I want to create an object with fake data for `Person` class, manually It'll take too much time, And `Person` class internally contains `Parties` class. 
Is there any simple ways to create Object with fake data. 
By using mockito we can create object, but again manually faking data is difficult.

```
class Person {
    int age;
    ArrayList<Parties> parties;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public ArrayList<Parties> getParties() {
        return parties;
    }

    public void setParties(ArrayList<Parties> parties) {
        this.parties = parties;
    }
}


class Parties {
    private int date, month, year;

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(int date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Finally, I found a solution for fake the object data from the class by using PODAM library in Java without the manual interaction.

We can use Podam library to fake data for object.

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
        <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code**

```
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
Person myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(Person.class);
```

Ref: [PODAM](http://mtedone.github.io/podam/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a one-liner using **Instancio**:

```java
Person person = Instancio.create(Person.class);
```

This returns a populated person including nested objects and collections. You can also use the builder API to customise generated values:

```java
Person person = Instancio.of(Person.class)
    .generate(field("age"), gen -> gen.ints().range(18, 65))
    .create();
```

If you use JUnit 5, you can also use it with `@ParameterizedTest`s:

```java
@ExtendWith(InstancioExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @InstancioSource
    void example(Person person) {
        // snip...
    }
}
```

You can find more examples in the [Instancio user guide](https://www.instancio.org).

https://www.github.com/instancio/instancio

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java Faker:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
    <version>0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Example usage:

```
Faker faker = new Faker();

String name = faker.name().fullName(); // Miss Samanta Schmidt
String firstName = faker.name().firstName(); // Emory
String lastName = faker.name().lastName(); // Barton

String streetAddress = faker.address().streetAddress(); // 60018 Sawayn Brooks Suite 449
```

Project site: http://dius.github.io/java-faker/

Comment: faker is for creating fake data, but for creating an object with fake data for class, requires so much manual interaction.

Comment: Not really, you just write a loop to populate whichever objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create `Parties` data if you are focussing on `Person` in your tests. You can always write like this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(new ArrayList()).when(your-mocked-person-object.getParties());
```

Comment: Create an object with fake data, without manual interaction. If I use mockito, again I have to fake all required fields. Instead is there any ways to create object with fake data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tricks that are often used for quick test data:

1) Create one person object as a base (manually). Various tests need only to modify parts of the data, such as on change the last name, etc.

2) Create a data generation utility, such as FakePersonCreator. It can use a combination of fixed strings and random data. Write a function that generates a person and have the tests use it.

3) Use real data as your test data. You can record it from a real program run, and export it into a file. Then you have two options:

- Read your test data from the file, on test run
- Write a utility that generates java code which builds the test
  data  (person ) according to your data file

4) Keep most of your test data (person) empty. Have each test only set the fields that it needs to check.

5) Use a mocking framework (e.g. Mockito) to mock the test data. Create mock objects that only return the fields actually needed for testing.